# Is there a list of neural style transfer architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-style-transfer

I'm trying to choose what neural style transfer architecture to use but I can't find a centralized list of all possible architectures I could choose from. Is there a place I could find this or could someone give me a summary of popular architectures that I can look in to?